# Not able to retrieve properties of a on fly created JSON object using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

In ng repeat I have used a radio button , which assigns entire person object to a scope veriable as mentioned below

```
 <li ng-repeat="person in people">
   <label>{{person.name}}
     <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.selectedPerson" name="name" value="{{person}}" required />
   </label>
</li>
```

so when i select a person i want to assign all of its properties to selectedPerson scope variable so that i can access and print its properties later to display information about the selected person.
Some how I am able to assign the object to the selectedPerson scope variable but not able to print its properties, Please have a look at JSFiddle of the scenario.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mayur_Randive/qz9rgdmd/)

I highly appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ngValue to bind the selected object to ngModel, this worked in your jsfiddle:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.selectedPerson" ng-value="person" name="name" value="{{person}}" required />
```

[Angular Documentation on ngValue](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) for further explanation .

Answer (score 3):

When you use the {{ }} notation, Angular evaluates the expression within the brackets on page load and then again if their expression outcome changes after a first cycle. If an object is within the curly brackets it is stringified, with the usual use case of debugging.

The 'value={{person}}' therefore is evaluated to a string which you then assign to the object selectedPerson.

Instead assign the name string to the name property of selectedPerson:
    ng-model='$parent.selectedPerson.name' value='{{person.name}}'

Comment: Phil's answer below is the proper way. Leaving mine up, because I hope it explains how angular evaluated expressions and why {{object}} actually evaluates to a string.

Comment: Thanks Tyler for your inputs , incase i just want to save one property in that case your suggestion will work , but i have 6 to 7 other properties as well which need to be scope into the scope variable .

Comment: Use Phil's answer. Like I said, you should really try to understand how angular evaluates expressions in the view versus using directives like ng-value to pass data.